# Power BI is there a way to separate a duration into 15 minutes intervals

Tags: powerbi

Is there a way to segregate a time duration (from date and time to date and time) into 15 minutes intervals using power BI.

I want to transform the first table into the second table.

| Name | Duration Start | Duration End | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mike | 07/07/2023 3:24:52 pm | 07/07/2023 4:20:15 pm | 00:55:23 |
| Mike | 08/07/2023 8:01:11 am | 08/07/2023 8:33:11 am | 00:32:00 |

| Name | Interval Start | Interval End | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mike | 07/07/2023 3:15:00 pm | 07/07/2023 3:30:00 pm | 00:05:52 |
| Mike | 07/07/2023 3:30:00 pm | 07/07/2023 3:45:00 pm | 00:15:00 |
| Mike | 07/07/2023 3:45:00 pm | 07/07/2023 4:00:00 pm | 00:15:00 |
| Mike | 07/07/2023 4:00:00 pm | 07/07/2023 4:15:00 pm | 00:15:00 |
| Mike | 07/07/2023 4:15:00 pm | 07/07/2023 4:30:00 pm | 00:09:45 |
| Mike | 08/07/2023 8:00:00 am | 08/07/2023 8:15:00 am | 00:13:49 |
| Mike | 08/07/2023 8:15:00 am | 08/07/2023 8:30:00 am | 00:15:00 |
| Mike | 08/07/2023 8:30:00 am | 08/07/2023 8:45:00 am | 00:11:49 |